# Optimal advanced settings for Gigabit NIC

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

My laptop's NIC is gigabit and I am searching for the optimal settings on the "Advanced" menu to take advantage of gigabit speeds.

The settings are:

1. Energy Effecient Ethernet
2. Green Ethernet
3. EEE Control Policies
4. Ethernet@WireSpeed
5. 802.3az EEE
6. Flow Control
7. ARP Offload
8. NS Offload
9. IPv4 Checksum Offload
10. TCP Checksum Offload
11. UDP Cehcksum Offload
12. Large Send Offload V2 (IPv4)
13. Jumbo Mtu
14. Receive Buffers
15. Transmit Buffers
16. Receive Side Scaling
17. Maximum Number of RSS Queues
18. Priority & VLAN
19. Interupt Moderation

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: This is a real banana skin of a question. What you have to remember is that the sole purpose of a NIC is to communicate with another device what your asking is how to optimise that best without knowing what the other device is or how it is setup. So settings like Jumbo MTU, Receive Side Scaling, Priority & VLAN, all of these fall back on your network topology and what is 'at the other end of the cable'. Very difficult to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are also 4 other Gigabit PCs & laptops in my network communicating with each other, so I'll configure them on the same way for best results.

Comment: For such a small environment you would most likely find Windows defaults will be better than anything you'll be able to tweak. What I would advise though is have a play with the power management settings because personally power management turning off my network connection drives me crazy!

Comment: None of the NIC settings will matter if the network itself isn't capable of those speeds. Is your network switch capable of gigabit speeds?

Comment: Yes, all of my switches are 10/100/1000.

Answer (score 0):

The [IEEE 802.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3) define standards who work in Phy Layer and Data Link Layer of [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

The Current modes of [Gigabit Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) are those:

- 1000BASE-CX
- 1000BASE-KX
- 1000BASE-SX
- 1000BASE-LX
- 1000BASE-LX
- 1000BASE-LX10
- 1000BASE-EX
- 1000BASE-ZX
- 1000BASE-BX10
- 1000BASE-T
- 1000BASE-TX

A complete description between them can be found [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#Varieties)

Usually links made a [Autonegotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) who define with mode can run between 2 ports.

About the functionabilities grant you in some cases more Performance and advanced functionality, as power safe. buffer tweaks, MTU size.

**And the Optimal Setting are set by default**.